# Append a String ":" to the every element in the array list of string and join as one single string

Tags: gwt

I need to Append a String ":" to the every element in the array list of string and join as one single string.

for example: i have array list containing elements as

(abc, def, ghi)

i need to display result as "abc:def:ghi" as one string.

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Asking questions like : "I need to ..." will be often be down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
str.add("AAA");
str.add("BBB");
str.add("CCC");
StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : str) {
   str2.append(s + ":");
}
// if you want to remove the last ':'
str2.deleteCharAt(str2.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Google's Guava Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) which happens to be GWT compatible:

```
String joinedList = Joiner.on(":").join(listOfThings);
```

Comment: @AndreiVolgin if you say that for every problem that you need 4 lines for, then you'll end up with a big program that does nothing relevant nor readable to your actual problem. So I think it is worth adding Guava for this, as many things in Guava will allow you to solve them in a more readable and concise way.

Comment: @froginvasion - Or you can end up with with dozens of dependencies and long start-up times. I am not against Guava - I use it all the time, but I would not use a new library just to replace a few lines of very simple Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Guava is a really, really cool library, but if you only need this litte part, you can just iterate with foreach over your list. Here is a example

```
package XXX.client.XXXXXX;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class JointString {
    public JointString() {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "ghi");

        StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();
        for (String string : list) {
            all.append(string);
            all.append(":");
            }

        RootPanel.get().add(new Label(all.toString()));

//if you don't want the ':' in the end...
StringBuilder all2 = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            all2.append(list.get(i));
            all.append(":");
        }
        all2.append(list.get(list.size() - 1));

    RootPanel.get().add(new Label(all2.toString()));

    }
}
```